# Replace consecutive 2 patterns

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

Input file:

```
101|12345|Stephen Lawrence\|Sam|02/02/16

102|12346|Michael\|Point|03/02/16

103|12347|Peter Man|01/02/16
```

Expected Output file:

```
101|12345|Stephen Lawrence Sam|02/02/16

102|12346|Michael Point|03/02/16

103|12347|Peter Man|01/02/16
```

Want to remove `"\|"` present between names.

Tried:

```
sed -e 's/"\|"/ /g' input_file
```

but no expected output.

Any inputs pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 sed 's/\\|/ /g' File
```

Output:

```
101|12345|Stephen Lawrence Sam|02/02/16

102|12346|Michael Point|03/02/16

103|12347|Peter Man|01/02/16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/e\\\|S/,"e S")sub(/l\\\|P/,"l P")}1' file

101|12345|Stephen Lawrence Sam|02/02/16

102|12346|Michael Point|03/02/16

103|12347|Peter Man|01/02/16
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.